# Detect Collision for an instantly refreshed object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collider

so i have an old code for a "Connect4" game it was written years ago, now i am having a big problem getting it results and rebuild them for a unity3D project.

the problem is that every gameObject (i've managed to instanciate in the scene) is, meant to be destroyed and reinstantiated every frame (and i have the feeling that is really more that a frame time); wanting to get the color of each gameobject in time seem to be really challenging, i am supposed now to not enter the code created i am only supposed to get the information from what i get as graphical results.

so now i have a board of boxes having a grid disposition that changes colors according to the player turns (red for the cp and yellow for the plyer).

i created a fixed boxes having colliders and wanted to get the game objects colliding with it everyframe but i failed .

PS: i tested this code and every solution i found in this community hope to find somehelp, thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SelectorCode : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collision other;

    public GameObject GO;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        GO = other.gameObject;


    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        GO = other.gameObject;


    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        GO = other.gameObject;


    }

    void Update()
    {

        GO = this.other.gameObject;

    }
}
```

Comment: "the problem is that every gameObject (i've managed to instanciate in the scene) is, meant to be destroyed and reinstantiated every frame" recreate all your object at each frame is really a bad idea,

Comment: i am really aware but as i said it was devloped years ago it is really old.

Comment: @Boo is extremely correct. Maybe it would be better to recreate the system, instead of continuing to use code you're aware is inherently flawed in its design.

Comment: yes forsure i really want to but i just can't is is a dignity question i think and now i am running really outof time :( i know it is really wrong but i got to do it . thnk you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the object to which the `SelectorCode` component is attached has a trigger collider (property "Is Trigger" is checked).

Next you'll get an error in the `Update`method with `GO = this.other.gameObject;` since other is never assigned. I think you should remove that line.

Finally, in `OnTriggerExit` you put in `GO` the object that is leaving your collider, that doesn't make sense, you should probably assign `GO` to `null` at this point :

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject == GO) 
    {
        GO = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want to detect the object constantly even if it is desroyed or recreated still i want to get the new instanciated object so i think i need the GO to detect the object even if we are exiting the trigger function

Comment: I don't think unity is going to be able to detect collisions for objects that are deleted and recreated each frame. Anyway maybe you can look at [Script execution order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html). But at least remove the line in `Update` which really can do nothing except throw an exception

Comment: Well then, there's no way around it, you won't be able to use unity/physx collision detection if you recreate all you objects at every frame. Either you fix the source of the problem or you implement your own collision detection, but I can't help you there, it's just too broad a problem.